# href link as <abc>, how to put inside href attribute

Tags: html, hyperlink, tags, field, href

I have a link which has the characters like  as a query, how do i write the code

this is my link 
"http://www.abc.com/abc.php?mydata=((a **<**near***>* a ( c d)and date=2011-01-01"

a ( c d)and date=2011-01-01 target=_blank>

this is not working

instead it is giving the above in the index.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `&lt;` and `&gt;` to output `<` and `>` respectively inside your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Just URL-encode the portion after mydata=. That's exactly the use of url-encoding: to transfer data in a URL that you can't otherwise put there (like spaces and <>). You can manually do so [here](http://www.albionresearch.com/misc/urlencode.php) or use a language function like [urlencode in PHP](http://www.php.net/urlencode) if that's what is generating the page.